# How to automate page number change in web scraping?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

My problem is that I have to change by hand the "pages_to_scrape" integer vector each time I scrape different parts of a given static site for which I dont know the exact page number. So, I want to automate this. In other words, when I dont know the page number beforehand, I want to be able to scrape all pages that are available.

```r
library(rvest)

base_url <- "https://morskidar.bg/products.php?category=pryasna-riba&page=%d"
scrape_prices <- function(page) {
  url <- sprintf(base_url, page)
  page_content <- read_html(url)
  pc <- page_content %>% 
    html_elements(".col-sm-6") %>%
    map_dfr(~ tibble(
      product = .x %>% 
        html_element(".shop-three-products-name a") %>% 
        html_text2(), 
      price = .x %>% 
        html_element(".shop-three-products-price") %>% 
        html_text2(),
      )) %>% 
    mutate(date = Sys.Date(),
               location = "Unknown",
               type = "Unknown",
               source = "Unknown", .before = product) %>% 
    separate_wider_delim(price, delim = " - ", names = c("unit", "price")) %>% 
    mutate(price = parse_number(price), unit = str_remove(unit, "\\.")) %>% 
    distinct()
  return(pc)
  }
pages_to_scrape <- 1:5
final_df <- map_dfr(pages_to_scrape, scrape_prices)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pagination links / page numbers are contained in the same html document:

```html
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="active"><a href="/products.php?category=pryasna-riba&amp;page=1" title="Pagination">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/products.php?category=pryasna-riba&amp;page=2" title="Pagination">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/products.php?category=pryasna-riba&amp;page=3" title="Pagination">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="/products.php?category=pryasna-riba&amp;page=4" title="Pagination">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="/products.php?category=pryasna-riba&amp;page=5" title="Pagination">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

, you can first scarpe values for your `pages_to_scrape` vector:

```r
library(rvest)
base_url <- "https://morskidar.bg/products.php?category=pryasna-riba&page=%d"
pages_to_scrape <- 
  sprintf(base_url, 1) |>
  read_html() |>
  html_elements("ul.pagination li") |> 
  html_text() |>
  as.integer()

pages_to_scrape
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

if the website is paginated, you could use a custom function like this to determine the pages:

```
get_total_pages <- function() {
  url <- sprintf(base_url, 1)
  page_content <- read_html(url)
  total_pages <- page_content %>% 
    html_element(".pagination li:last-child a") %>% 
    html_attr("data-ci-pagination-page")
  return(as.integer(total_pages))
}

# Check the total number of pages
total_pages <- get_total_pages()

# Scrape prices for all pages
pages_to_scrape <- 1:total_pages
final_df <- map_dfr(pages_to_scrape, scrape_prices)
```

I tried opening the url to inspect html content but it just loads a logo and nothing else so let me know if the structure varies and I can adapt the custom function to help or this could be a starting point for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Here is the error that it throws: Error in 1:total_pages : NA/NaN argument.

Comment: does the website use pagination?

Comment: Yep. Otherwise, I wouldn't have any trouble.